# " java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "18,June 2017, 5:39AM"

Tags: java, datetime, datetime-format, datetime-parsing

I have a date in string and values like `"18,June 2017, 5:39AM"` and 
`"01,July 2017, 9:09AM"`. Now I want to convert these dates to `"2017-06-18 18:47:17"` in this format . I have use this code:

```
String testDate = "18,June 2017, 5:39AM";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd,MMMM yyyy , HH:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date = formatter.parse(testDate);
System.out.println(date);
```

But I have got an exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "18,June 2017, 5:39AM"
>           at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)

How can I convert `"18,June 2017, 6:47PM"` to `"2017-06-18 18:47:17"`?

Comment: From your example it looks like the PM/AM-part of the input date is directly adjacent to the minute part. But in your format you got a space between minute and the am/pm-marker

Comment: There is space between yyyy and ,, after removing space and code change suggested by dpr it doesn't give parse exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must add single quotes arround the comma and remove the blank between `mm` and `a`

```
 SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd','MMMM yyyy',' HH:mma", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Define a formatting pattern to match your input.

Specify a `Locale` to determine the human language used for translating the name of the month, and to determine the cultural norms for deciding localization issues.

```
String input = "18,June 2017, 5:39AM" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "d,MMMM uuuu, h:mma").withLocale( Locale.US ) ;   
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/ash4JI).

By the way, this formatting pattern is terrible. Educate the publisher of your data about the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.